# DataTable returns "0" as value

Tags: c#, datatable, rows

I have a problem with getting data from sqlite database. Normally it works fine in other forms but on my last query all the returns "0".

```
try
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection baglanti = new SQLiteConnection(Uygulama.baglantiMetni))
            {
                if (baglanti.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    baglanti.Open();

                string sorgu = "SELECT tyOzellikDegerID, tyOzellikDegeri FROM tblTYKategoriOzellikDegerleri WHERE tyOzellikID=:ozellikkodu";

                using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sorgu, baglanti))
                {
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(":ozellikkodu", Convert.ToInt32(kod));
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);


                    cmbTYOzellikDegerleri.DisplayMember = "tyOzellikDegeri";
                    cmbTYOzellikDegerleri.ValueMember = "tyOzellikDegerID";
                    cmbTYOzellikDegerleri.DataSource = dt;

                    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dr["tyOzellikDegeri"].ToString());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception hata)
        {
            if (Uygulama.logTut == 1)
                Fonksiyonlar.logYaz("FrmTeyStokListesi - ggOzellikDegeleri(" + kod + ") - " + hata.Message);
        }
```

DataRow returns "0".

But if I run the code on sqlitedatabrowser it works fine.

I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: Your parameter name does not match your query. `:kod != :ozellikkodu`

Comment: normally it was correct but i pasted the statement that i tried. thanks for your attention.

Comment: Then I would say your parameter value is not what you think it is or you are hitting a different database with different data. Obviously we cannot run this code and see what your query returns, debug the code, break on `da.Fill(dt)` and use the debugger's visualizer to see what is in the data table.

Comment: Here is the screenshots of my code and returned values when i run it on sqlitedatabrowser
[link](https://teybilisim.com/resimdeposu/donen1.png)
[link](https://teybilisim.com/resimdeposu/donen2.png)
Normally the display data must be "Çocuk".

Comment: I have recreated the table and deleted all data in it. Then i populated data again from remote then it was solved. The reason was the structure of data i think. Because i used this code in all of querying in my project.